# HTTPD load balancer shows duplicated information about nodes

Tags: load-balancing

I have enabled the HTTPD LoadBalancer Manager as:

```
<location "/balancer-manager">
        SetHandler balancer-manager
        allow from all
</location>
```

But when I access the HTTP interface, I can see that the nodes are duplicated, I mean by this, if the balancer has 3 nodes I see 6 entries...why can this be happening?

```
> Load Balancer Manager for 172.29.164.174
Server Version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2
Server Built: Mar 3 2015 12:06:14
LoadBalancer Status for balancer://rws
StickySession   Timeout FailoverAttempts    Method
ROUTEID 0   5   byrequests

Worker URL  Route   RouteRedir  Factor  Set Status  Elected To  From
http://172.29.164.172:8080  RWS_Node_Ol_1       1   0   Init Ok 52476   73M 393M
http://172.29.164.173:8080  RWS_Node_Ol_2       1   0   Init Ok 52476   74M 391M
http://172.29.164.174:8080  RWS_Node_Ol_3       1   0   Init Ok 52476   74M 409M
http://172.29.164.172:8080  RWS_Node_Ol_1       1   0   Init Ok 52476   73M 393M
http://172.29.164.173:8080  RWS_Node_Ol_2       1   0   Init Ok 52476   74M 391M
http://172.29.164.174:8080  RWS_Node_Ol_3       1   0   Init Ok 52476   74M 409M
```

This is my LB configuration

```
<Proxy balancer://rws>
BalancerMember http://172.29.164.172:8080 route=RWS_Node_Ol_1
BalancerMember http://172.29.164.173:8080 route=RWS_Node_Ol_2
BalancerMember http://172.29.164.174:8080 route=RWS_Node_Ol_3
Header add Set-Cookie "ROUTEID=.%{BALANCER_WORKER_ROUTE}e; path=/" env=BALANCER_ROUTE_CHANGED
ProxySet stickysession=ROUTEID
</Proxy>
ProxyPass /api balancer://rws/api
ProxyPass /internal-api balancer://rws/internal-api
```

Answer (score 0):

Well...my issue was that a clever guy left 2 config files with extension conf at the conf.d folder...changed extension and fixed